# Función .map no me devuelve los datos a la hora de cargar el componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-hooks, djangorestframework

muy buenas a todos... resulta que estoy haciendo una aplicación web que muestra los datos registrados en una base de datos MYSQL. Esta aplicación está hecha con React y Django como restAPI. En un componente tengo la misma instrucción para que me mapee los datos de la base de datos pero en este componente si se ven y en el otro no me muestra ni la página... Les adjunto el código y el error.

ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'


import * as ServerMinera from './serverAPI/mineraServer'

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FloatingLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';




//Nota, se podria agregar un modal haciendo otro component que este dentro de appjs y que sea llamado cuando se presione el boton. Se podria usar la sgte linea de codigo
// para poder hacerla funcional y que este boton navegue hasta el component que contiene el modal para poder mostrarlo.
// navigates(`/inventario/${objeto.idObjeto}`
// objeto.idObjeto && obtenerObjeto(objeto.idObjeto)




export const GestionarCuentas = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    //Se usa para obtener los datos del json que sostienen los objetos
    const [cuentas, setcuentas] = useState([]);

    const listarCuentas = async () =>{
        try {
            const res = await ServerMinera.listarUsers();
            const datos = await res.json();
            //console.log(datos); Esto llama los arreglos a la consola para checkear
            //Renderiza los elementos encontrados.
            setcuentas(datos.cuentas);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    //Llama a listar objetos para que pueda ser desplegado en la tabla.
    useEffect( () => {
        listarCuentas();
    },[]);

    //Se establece el estado inicial del Objeto a la hora de querer agregarlo a la base de datos.
    const estadoCuentaInicial = {idUsuario:0,nombre_propietario:"",apellido_propietario:"",nombre_usuario:"",contrasena:"",idTipo_bodeguero_id:""};

    //Hook que hace que a objeto y setObjeto tenga el estado de uso del estado inicial del objeto.
    const [cuenta, setcuenta] = useState(estadoCuentaInicial);

    //Hook que verifica si los datos dentro de las inputs han cambiado o no.
    const manejarCambiosEntrada = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name);
        setcuenta({ ...cuenta,[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    //Hook que maneja a donde van a parar los datos al presionar el boton registrar objeto.
    const manejarSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            let res;
            if (!params.idUsuario) {
                res = await ServerMinera.registrarUser(cuenta);
                const datos = await res.json();
                console.log(datos);
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                await ServerMinera.actualizarObjeto(params.idUsuario,cuenta)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const borrarCuenta = async (idUsuario) => {
        //console.log(idObjeto); Para verificar la recuperacion de la id a la hora de presionar el boton de borrado.
        //Espera a que reciba la respuesta de la api al mandarle la id del objeto, si la encuentra, borrara el dato solicitado a borrar.
        await ServerMinera.borrarUser(idUsuario);
        //Renderiza la lista nuevamente
        listarCuentas();
    }

    const obtenerCuenta = async (idUsuario) => {
        try {
            const res = await ServerMinera.obtenerUsers(idUsuario);
            const datos = await res.json();
            //console.log(datos); Para verificar a traves de consola si se obtienen los datos del boton presionado.
            const { nombre_propietario, apellido_propietario, nombre_usuario, contrasena, idTipo_bodeguero_id } = datos.cuenta;
            setcuenta({ nombre_propietario, apellido_propietario, nombre_usuario, contrasena, idTipo_bodeguero_id });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (params.idUsuario) {
            obtenerCuenta(params.idUsuario)
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
        <div id='tituloInventario'>
            <h1 className='text-center'>Ingresar objetos</h1>
        </div>
        <br />
            <form onSubmit={manejarSubmit}>
                <div id='campoNombre'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingNombreObjeto'
                            label = "Nombre Propietario"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='nombre_propietario' type='text' placeholder='Ej: Juanr' defaultValue={cuenta.nombre_propietario} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoCantidad'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingCantidad'
                            label = "Apellido Propietario"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='apellido_propietario' type='text' placeholder='Ej: Martinez' defaultValue={cuenta.apellido_propietario} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoDescripcion'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingDescripcion'
                            label = "Nombre de Usuario"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='nombre_usuario' type='text' placeholder='Ej: jmartinez' defaultValue={cuenta.nombre_usuario} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoPrestatario'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingPrestatario'
                            label = "Contraseña"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='contrasena' type='text' placeholder='Ej: jmartinez123' defaultValue={cuenta.contrasena} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoIdTipoObjeto'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'inTipoObjeto'
                            label = "ID Tipo Bodeguero"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='idTipo_bodeguero' type='text' placeholder='Ej: 2 - Jefe' defaultValue={cuenta.idTipo_bodeguero_id} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                    {
                        params.idUsuario?(
                            <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
                            <i className="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>
                            ACTUALIZAR OBJETO
                            </Button>

                        ) : (
                            <Button variant='success' type='submit'>
                            <i className="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>
                            AGREGAR OBJETO
                            </Button>
                        )
                    }

                </div>
            </form>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h1 className='text-center'>Registros</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table className="table table-striped mt-5">
                    <thead className='bg-dark text-white'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombre Propietario</th>
                            <th>Apellido Propietario</th>
                            <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>
                            <th>Contraseña</th>
                            <th>Tipo de Bodeguero</th>
                            <th>Modificar</th>
                            <th>Eliminar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {cuentas.map(cuenta =>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{cuenta.idUsuario}</td>
                            <td>{cuenta.nombre_propietario}</td>
                            <td>{cuenta.apellido_propietario}</td>
                            <td>{cuenta.nombre_usuario}</td>
                            <td>{cuenta.contrasena}</td>
                            <td>{cuenta.idTipo_bodeguero_id}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Button variant='warning' id='btnEditarCuenta' onClick={() => navigate(`/gestionarCuentas/${cuenta.idUsuario}`)}>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M12.854.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L10.5 1.793 14.207 5.5l1.647-1.646a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3zm.646 6.061L9.793 2.5 3.293 9H3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.207l6.5-6.5zm-7.468 7.468A.5.5 0 0 1 6 13.5V13h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10h-.5a.499.499 0 0 1-.175-.032l-.179.178a.5.5 0 0 0-.11.168l-2 5a.5.5 0 0 0 .65.65l5-2a.5.5 0 0 0 .168-.11l.178-.178z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button variant='danger' id='btnBorrarCuenta' onClick={() => cuenta.idUsuario && borrarCuenta(cuenta.idUsuario)}>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash3-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M11 1.5v1h3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-.538l-.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 1 11.115 16h-6.23a2 2 0 0 1-1.994-1.84L2.038 3.5H1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 0h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 1.5Zm-5 0v1h4v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5ZM4.5 5.029l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 0 .998-.06l-.5-8.5a.5.5 0 1 0-.998.06Zm6.53-.528a.5.5 0 0 0-.528.47l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .998.058l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.47-.528ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5Z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Y este vendría siendo el código del componente Inventario que sí hace la función de mostrar lo que contiene en la base de datos

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'


import * as ServerMinera from './serverAPI/mineraServer'

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FloatingLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';




//Nota, se podria agregar un modal haciendo otro component que este dentro de appjs y que sea llamado cuando se presione el boton. Se podria usar la sgte linea de codigo
// para poder hacerla funcional y que este boton navegue hasta el component que contiene el modal para poder mostrarlo.
// navigates(`/inventario/${objeto.idObjeto}`
// objeto.idObjeto && obtenerObjeto(objeto.idObjeto)




export const Inventario = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    //Se usa para obtener los datos del json que sostienen los objetos
    const [objetos, setObjetos] = useState([]);

    const listarObjetos = async () =>{
        try {
            const res = await ServerMinera.listarObjetos();
            const datos = await res.json();
            //console.log(datos); Esto llama los arreglos a la consola para checkear
            //Renderiza los elementos encontrados.
            setObjetos(datos.objetos);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    //Llama a listar objetos para que pueda ser desplegado en la tabla.
    useEffect( () => {
        listarObjetos();
    },[]);

    //Se establece el estado inicial del Objeto a la hora de querer agregarlo a la base de datos.
    const estadoObjetoInicial = {idObjeto:0,nombre:"",cantidad:1,descripcion:"",prestatario:"",id_tipo_id:""};

    //Hook que hace que a objeto y setObjeto tenga el estado de uso del estado inicial del objeto.
    const [objeto, setObjeto] = useState(estadoObjetoInicial);

    //Hook que verifica si los datos dentro de las inputs han cambiado o no.
    const manejarCambiosEntrada = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name);
        setObjeto({ ...objeto,[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    //Hook que maneja a donde van a parar los datos al presionar el boton registrar objeto.
    const manejarSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            let res;
            if (!params.idObjeto) {
                res = await ServerMinera.registrarObjeto(objeto);
                const datos = await res.json();
                console.log(datos);
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                await ServerMinera.actualizarObjeto(params.idObjeto,objeto)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const borrarRegistro = async (idObjeto) => {
        //console.log(idObjeto); Para verificar la recuperacion de la id a la hora de presionar el boton de borrado.
        //Espera a que reciba la respuesta de la api al mandarle la id del objeto, si la encuentra, borrara el dato solicitado a borrar.
        await ServerMinera.borrarObjeto(idObjeto);
        //Renderiza la lista nuevamente
        listarObjetos();
    }

    const obtenerObjeto = async (idObjeto) => {
        try {
            const res = await ServerMinera.obtenerObjeto(idObjeto);
            const datos = await res.json();
            //console.log(datos); Para verificar a traves de consola si se obtienen los datos del boton presionado.
            const { nombre, cantidad, descripcion, prestatario, id_tipo_id } = datos.objeto;
            setObjeto({ nombre, cantidad, descripcion, prestatario, id_tipo_id });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (params.idObjeto) {
            obtenerObjeto(params.idObjeto)
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
        <div id='tituloInventario'>
            <h1 className='text-center'>Ingresar objetos</h1>
        </div>
        <br />
            <form onSubmit={manejarSubmit}>
                <div id='campoNombre'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingNombreObjeto'
                            label = "Nombre Objeto"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='nombre' type='text' placeholder='Ej: Muelas Chancador' defaultValue={objeto.nombre} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoCantidad'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingCantidad'
                            label = "Cantidad"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='cantidad' type='number' placeholder='Ej: 2' defaultValue={objeto.cantidad} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoDescripcion'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingDescripcion'
                            label = "Descripcion"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='descripcion' type='text' placeholder='Ej: yadayadayadayadayadayada' defaultValue={objeto.descripcion} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoPrestatario'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'floatingPrestatario'
                            label = "Prestatario"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='prestatario' type='text' placeholder='Ej: Jaimito El Cartero' defaultValue={objeto.prestatario} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div id='campoIdTipoObjeto'>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FloatingLabel
                            controlId = 'inTipoObjeto'
                            label = "ID Tipo Objeto"
                            className = 'mb-3'
                        >
                            <Form.Control name='id_tipo_id' type='text' placeholder='Ej: 2 - Herramienta' defaultValue={objeto.id_tipo_id} onChange={manejarCambiosEntrada}/>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                    {
                        params.id?(
                            <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
                            <i className="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>
                            ACTUALIZAR OBJETO
                            </Button>

                        ) : (
                            <Button variant='success' type='submit'>
                            <i className="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>
                            AGREGAR OBJETO
                            </Button>
                        )
                    }

                </div>
            </form>
            <br />
            <div id='tituloTablaInventario'>
                <h1 className='text-center'>Registros</h1>
            </div>
            <div id='tablaInventario'>
                <table className="table table-striped mt-5">
                    <thead className='bg-dark text-white' id='headerTablaObjeto'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Descripcion</th>
                            <th>Prestatario</th>
                            <th>Tipo Objeto</th>
                            <th>Modificar</th>
                            <th>Eliminar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='cuerpoTablaObjeto'>
                        {objetos?.map(objeto =>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{objeto.idObjeto}</td>
                            <td>{objeto.nombre}</td>
                            <td>{objeto.cantidad}</td>
                            <td>{objeto.descripcion}</td>
                            <td>{objeto.prestatario}</td>
                            <td>{objeto.id_tipo_id}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Button variant='warning' id='btnEditarObjeto' onClick={() => navigate(`/inventario/${objeto.idObjeto}`)}>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M12.854.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L10.5 1.793 14.207 5.5l1.647-1.646a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3zm.646 6.061L9.793 2.5 3.293 9H3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.207l6.5-6.5zm-7.468 7.468A.5.5 0 0 1 6 13.5V13h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10h-.5a.499.499 0 0 1-.175-.032l-.179.178a.5.5 0 0 0-.11.168l-2 5a.5.5 0 0 0 .65.65l5-2a.5.5 0 0 0 .168-.11l.178-.178z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button variant='danger' id='btnBorrarObjeto' onClick={() => objeto.idObjeto && borrarRegistro(objeto.idObjeto)}>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash3-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M11 1.5v1h3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-.538l-.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 1 11.115 16h-6.23a2 2 0 0 1-1.994-1.84L2.038 3.5H1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 0h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 1.5Zm-5 0v1h4v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5ZM4.5 5.029l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 0 .998-.06l-.5-8.5a.5.5 0 1 0-.998.06Zm6.53-.528a.5.5 0 0 0-.528.47l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .998.058l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.47-.528ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5Z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: podrias poner un `console.log` antes de cada uno de los `.map` que tienes... asi te das cuenta cual es la variables que está `undefined`

Comment: Al final encontre una solucion al problema, cuando me desocupe la publico. Muchas gracias... No se depurar mucho en JS debido a que recien estoy aprendiendo :c